# Backup external harddrive online

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive

My neighbor was asking me for help with her backups.  After a few back and forths, this is what I know.

- She doesn't have a home computer.
- She does have a laptop from her
  school (she's a teacher)
- She backs up all of her files from her
  phone/cameras to an external harddrive that I have to assume she
  access via her laptop. So, the laptop CAN be used as an intermediary.
- On her external harddrive, she's got probably 20GB or so of pictures and
  videos of her family.

How should she back this up? I personally use Mozy, but I don't think they allow external harddrives to be backed up.  In addition, I'm not sure that she could configure Mozy to not backup the stuff on the laptop, which she doesn't want to back up.

Comment: what is she backing up? Her laptop, or the external? Also what Operating system is the laptop, you can configure backups to do just certain folders which you choose. Then create a shortcut to the desktop so she can do it easily. If she's backing up files from the laptop.

Comment: You could also advise a 64GB thumbdrive. It's always better to have 2 backups (in case one backup drive fails).

Comment: She wants to backup only the external HD.  The OS is a Windows flavor (probably 7).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that Mozy won't allow you to back up an external drive? Why? It is supposed to back up any drives of your machine. If Mozy really can not do it, I'd try [Degoo](https://degoo.com/). They offer 100 GB for free, so she won't need to pay anything